# Language environment UTF-8 cause Emacs to exhaust CPU

Tags: emacs

I'm running Emacs 25 on Windows 10. The default language environment is "English", which works correctly.

This line of code cause Emacs to exhaust CPU and to respond slowly when editing **Chinese** text.

```
(set-language-environment 'utf-8)
```

Please help me to find out why. If you google the code, you may find this is the recommended configuration by many people. I minimize my ~/.emacs.d/init.el into only two lines. The problem still remains.

```
(set-language-environment 'utf-8)
(provide 'init)
```

Here is the profiling result of `profiler-report`:

```
- command-execute                                                1290  94%
 - call-interactively                                            1290  94%
  - funcall-interactively                                        1125  82%
   - previous-line                                                679  49%
    - line-move                                                   679  49%
       line-move-visual                                           584  42%
   - next-line                                                    367  26%
    - line-move                                                   367  26%
       line-move-visual                                           367  26%
   - execute-extended-command                                      78   5%
    - sit-for                                                      78   5%
       redisplay                                                   77   5%
   - yank                                                           1   0%
      insert-for-yank                                               1   0%
  - byte-code                                                     165  12%
   - read-extended-command                                        165  12%
    - completing-read                                             165  12%
     - completing-read-default                                    165  12%
        read-from-minibuffer                                      163  11%
- ...                                                              78   5%
   Automatic GC                                                    78   5%
```

Here is the environment information:

- emacs-bin-w64-20151110-9145e79.7z
  http://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64/
- Windows 10